# Display Current Time using shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode, date-time

I am using the below code to display current time in php supported time zones:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$currentTime = date( 'd-m-Y h:i:s A', time () );
echo $currentTime;
?>
```

We need to create few different pages in wordpress to display current time in different supported cities / timezones in wordpress pages through shortcodes in following format:

```
[current_time timezone="Africa/Accra"]
```

Please help us to write this function.

Comment: And what solutions have you already tried? Could you show us your current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in Theme function file functions.php

```
    function timeZone_funch( $atts ) 
    {
        extract(shortcode_atts(array('timezone'    => 'Asia/Kolkata'), $atts)); 
/* Asia/Kolkata is default Timezone */
        $output             = '';
        if (in_array($timezone, DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()))
        {
            date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
            $currentTime = date( 'd-m-Y h:i:s A');
            $output = $currentTime;
        }
        else {
            $output = "Invalid Timezone";
        }

        return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'current_time', 'timeZone_funch' );
```

USAGE:  **[current_time timezone="Africa/Accra"]**

Comment: This is perfect. I am not sure why the question was down voted.

Answer (score 0):

/* Africa/Nairobi is default Timezone */
$output             = '';
if (in_array($timezone, DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()))
{
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$currentTime = date( 'h:i:s A');
$output = $currentTime;
}
else {
$output = "Invalid Timezone";
}

```
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'current_time', 'timeZone_funch' );
```